# how to make '127.0.0.1:1110/abcService.svc' url accessible

Tags: networking, nginx, port, server, web-hosting

I have a abcService.svc already created and ready to be accessed. But I want it available on a specific port in my case 1110. How do I achieve this? I have nginx and glassfish server up and running. Which of the two will be a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

This config will help you:

```
...
    server {
       listen 1110;
       root /path/to/abcService.svc;
       .... Your directives
    }
```

After adding this to your conf file you have to reload nginx.